# Returning wrong intent should be buy_food not hello

Tags: node.js, nlp

I'm new using node-nlp but according to the examples I saw and the data I provided I should get a buy_food intent. But I'm not, it's returning hello intent. Any suggestions? If I remove the

manager.addDocument('en', 'hi', 'hello') line, it returns the right intent.

Any suggestions?

```
const { NlpManager } = require('node-nlp');
const manager = new NlpManager({ languages: 'en', ner: { threshold: 0.8 } });

manager.addNamedEntityText('drink', 'sprite', ['en'], ['sprite']);
manager.addNamedEntityText('size', 'large', ['en'], ['large', 'big']);

manager.addDocument('en', 'hello', 'hello');
manager.addDocument('en', 'hi', 'hello');

manager.addDocument('en', '%size% %drink%', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i want %drink% please', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i want %size% %drink% please', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i want a %drink% please', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i want a %size% %drink% please', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i want to order a %size% %drink%', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'i want to order a %drink%', 'buy_food');
manager.addDocument('en', 'bye', 'bye');
manager.addDocument('en', 'bye bye', 'bye');

manager.addAnswer('en', 'hello', 'Welcome! How may I help you?');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'bye', 'Till next time');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'bye', 'see you soon!');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'buy_food', 'Got it, what else?');
manager.addAnswer('en', 'buy_food', 'Ok. Next item.');

var text = 'i want a large sprite';
(async () => {
    await manager.train();
    var result= await manager.process('en', text);
    console.log(result);
})();
```

The result is

```
{ utterance: 'i want a large sprite',
  locale: 'en',
  languageGuessed: false,
  localeIso2: 'en',
  language: 'English',
  domain: 'default',
  classifications:
   [ { label: 'hello', value: 0.5484776863751949 },
     { label: 'buy_food', value: 0.36024868417489125 },
     { label: 'bye', value: 0.09127362944991388 } ],
  intent: 'hello',
  score: 0.5484776863751949,
  entities:
   [ { start: 9,
       end: 13,
       len: 5,
       levenshtein: 0,
       accuracy: 1,
       option: 'large',
       sourceText: 'large',
       entity: 'size',
       utteranceText: 'large' },
     { start: 15,
       end: 20,
       len: 6,
       levenshtein: 0,
       accuracy: 1,
       option: 'sprite',
       sourceText: 'sprite',
       entity: 'drink',
       utteranceText: 'sprite' } ],
  sentiment:
   { score: 0.29699999999999993,
     comparative: 0.05939999999999999,
     vote: 'positive',
     numWords: 5,
     numHits: 6,
     type: 'senticon',
     language: 'en' },
  actions: [],
  srcAnswer: 'Welcome! How may I help you?',
  answer: 'Welcome! How may I help you?' }
```

Comment: Hi, I try your example with last version of node-nlp, and it return: `classifications:
   [ { label: 'buy_food', value: 1 },
     { label: 'hello', value: 0 },
     { label: 'bye', value: 0 } ],
  intent: 'buy_food',
  score: 1,
  entities:
   [ { start: 9,
       end: 13,
       len: 5,
       levenshtein: 0,
       accuracy: 1,
       option: 'large',
       sourceText: 'large',
       entity: 'size',
       utteranceText: 'large' },
     { start: 15,
       end: 20,
       len: 6,
       levenshtein: 0,
       accuracy: 1,
       option: 'sprite',
       sourceText],`

Comment: Make sense, I was using version 3.2.0, but I just made a test with version 3.2.1 and it's working properly. Thanks!